# IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Invalid initial capacity' in Spark on Google DataProc

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml, google-cloud-dataproc

I am currently trying to run a ml decision tree on a large dataset (30 mio observations, 13 variables) in Spark 2.0.0 on Google DataProc.
When I execute:

```
labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="Target", outputCol="indexedLabel").fit(data)
```

I receive the following error:

> IllegalArgumentException: u'requirement failed: Invalid initial capacity'

I do not find a lot information about this error on the internet. Can somebody please explain what the problem is and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The error was due to the fact that the input dataframe (data) was defined but empty.